# How to use Child functions from Parent pointers?

Tags: c++

Here is a sample parent and child I'm working with.

```
class Home{
    public:
        virtual void input();
        virtual void output();
    private:
};

class Ocelot : public Home{
    public:
        void input(istream& ins = cin);
        void output(ostream& outs = cout);
    private:
        int revolvers;
        double shadeCover;
        int waterSources;
};
```

And here is my main where I'm trying to make a pointer that can hold different kinds of children and call their functions.

```
int main(){
    list<Home> animals;
    Home * ptr;
    ptr = new Ocelot;
    ptr->input();
    ptr->output();
    return 0;
}
```

When I attempt to compile, I'm just getting undefined references to Home::input and Home::output. What exactly is it that I'm doing incorrectly here? Thank you for your time.

Edit: In case it wasn't clear, I am trying to call the Ocelot input and output functions. The Home ones don't exist.

Comment: Ocelot doesn't implement Home's virtual interfaces (ocelot has istream and ostream as arguments to input and output respectively). Even though you've specified the default values, the compiler can't make the connection.

Comment: When I attempt to put the same arguments in the Home virtual functions, I just end up getting undefined reference to Home::input(istream &) in my compiler.

Comment: Your `input` and `output` functions have different parameters. One has no parameters, the other has a default parameter. That could be allowed, but I would double-check, as it seems off to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Home::input` and `Home::output` don't require implementations, make them pure virtual functions:

```
virtual void input() = 0;
virtual void output() = 0;
```

Otherwise, you need to define an implementation for them in `Home` so the linker doesn't complain about it:

```
virtual void input() { /* code */ }
virtual void output() { /* code */ }
```

You will also need to make the signatures of `input` and `output` the same for the base class `Home` and derived class `Ocelot`. Either add the stream parameters to the signatures of `Home::input` and `Home::output` or remove them from `Ocelot::input` and `Ocelot::output`.

Additionally: `list<Home>` will cause problems for you; you will need to use `list<Home*>` instead so the base class (which is now abstract because of the pure virtual functions) is not being instantiated.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. When I attempt to change Home::input and Home::output to purely virtual functions, I am alerted that I can't allocate an object of type Ocelot because the above mentioned functions are abstract.

My end goal for this is a having a linked list of many different kinds of Home children and being able to move through them with an iterator while outputting.

Comment: @stumpbeard I would remove the parameters in your `Ocelot` class, or move them up to `Home` class so they are visible within your list. I'm not sure if having the derived method parameters will compile properly or not - I thought I remembered having written something like that before, but I might be remembering wrong. I'll update once I have a confirmed answer.

Comment: @stumpbeard I've updated my answer, seems that the different signatures won't work at all (even with the default arguments).

Comment: I believe this will get me on the right track. When I get back home I will test. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> list animals;

You cannot do this if `Home` is an abstract class. std containers cannot hold abstract classes (interfaces), simply because these cannot be constructed or instanciated. What you can do is:

```
list<Home*> animals;
```

Apart from this, make your `input()` and `output()` methods pure virtual (`=0;`) and do implement them in child classes that inherit the `Home` interface.